# Conversion to Machine language

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

I am a student of Computer science, I have a course of COAL(Computer Organizing and assembly Language), I was trying to convert Assembly language into Machine language, but I am having some difficulties.

For example if I have to convert MOV [SI + 490], SP into Machine language, so how would I do it?
I know some of the terms like d, w, mod, reg, r/m.

Some useful Link would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between "Machine language" and "Assembly Language"? Are you talking about manual assembly? e.g. Assembler instructions like "MOV X" to Bytes like "0x80 0xff"?

Comment: Machine language is consist of 1 and 0. I want to know how to convert a assembly part into machine language(in numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look up what kind of instruction it actually is, `mov r/m16, r16` and it looks to be in 16bit mode so the format is `89 /r`.

Then encode the [ModR/M](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm16.htm), the rm part is `si + sword`, the r is `sp`, so we get `A4`.

So in total:

```
89 A4 EA 01
```

Comment: I am having problem in mod, means i don't know how to choose mod value?

Comment: @AniqMakhani look in that table I linked to, it's split in 4 categories based on mod.

Comment: Yes, 00, 01, 10, 11 but how will i decide which mod value to choose?

Comment: @AniqMakhani based on the form of your r/m operand.

Comment: I am stuck in this question MOV DS,AX. We don't have any value for DS. So how we are suppose to do it?

Comment: @AniqMakhani `mov` to/from a segment register is a different instruction, `8E D8` for this one. Segment registers are in the r list only.